# Logging in to a web site

Tags: c#, authentication, screen-scraping

I am new to C# but it happens that I need to programmatically login to a particular web site for screen-scraping in C#.  I have done on-line research (this site has been particularly helpful) and I have learnt that I need to use one of the following objects/classes in order to login: `WebRequest/WebResponse`, `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse`, `WebClient`, and also that I need to pass cookies that I receive from the web site to subsequent (screen scraping) requests.  I, however, have not been able to successfully login, and at this point I have ran out of ideas.  I want to login on the home page ------ and then screen scrape a number of pages like this one: -------.  The web site works like this: It allows one to access pages like the one I have referenced, but unless a user is logged in, it returns asterisks in some of the fields.  I presume that it means that the content is dynamically generated, which I suspect may be the underlying cause of my login troubles.  I am including the code that I am using to login to the web site:

```
    class Program
{
    private static string link_main_page = "-----------";
    private static string link_target_page = "------------";
    private static string authorization_param = "----------";

    private static void LoginUsingTheHttpWebRequestClass()
    {
        HttpWebRequest MyLoginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link_main_page);
        MyLoginRequest.Method = "POST";
        MyLoginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        MyLoginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        MyLoginRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authorization_param);
        MyLoginRequest.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
        Stream sendStream = MyLoginRequest.GetRequestStream();
        sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);

        HttpWebResponse MyLoginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyLoginRequest.GetResponse();
        CookieCollection MyCookieCollection = new CookieCollection();
        MyCookieCollection.Add(MyLoginResponse.Cookies);
        foreach (Cookie MyCookie in MyCookieCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", MyCookie.Name, MyCookie.Value);
        }

        HttpWebRequest MyGetRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link_target_page);
        MyGetRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        MyGetRequest.Method = "GET";
        MyGetRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
        MyGetRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        MyGetRequest.CookieContainer.Add(MyCookieCollection);

        HttpWebResponse MyGetResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyGetRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream;
        stream = MyGetResponse.GetResponseStream();

        string s;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("TheFile.htm"))
            {

                sw.Write(s);
                sw.Close();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void LoginUsingTheWebRequestClass()
    {
        WebRequest MyLoginRequest = WebRequest.Create(link_main_page);
        MyLoginRequest.Method = "POST";
        MyLoginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authorization_param);
        MyLoginRequest.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
        Stream sendStream = MyLoginRequest.GetRequestStream();
        sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);

        WebResponse MyLoginResponse = MyLoginRequest.GetResponse();
        string CookieHeader;
        CookieHeader = MyLoginResponse.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
        Console.WriteLine(CookieHeader);

        WebRequest MyGetRequest = WebRequest.Create(link_target_page);
        MyGetRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        MyGetRequest.Method = "GET";
        MyGetRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", CookieHeader);

        WebResponse MyGetResponse = MyGetRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream;
        stream = MyGetResponse.GetResponseStream();

        string s;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("TheFile2.htm"))
            {
                sw.Write(s);
                sw.Close();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Using the HttpWebRequest Class");
        LoginUsingTheHttpWebRequestClass();
        Console.WriteLine("Login Using the WebRequest Class");
        LoginUsingTheWebRequestClass(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Done!  Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Neither the attempt to login using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse nor the attempt to login using WebRequest/WebResponse works.  The first one returns a cookie that looks like this:
    PHPSESSID=hncrr0...
The second one returns a cookie that looks like that:
    PHPSESSID=88dn1n9...; path=/
These cookies look suspicious to me.  For one thing they look different from the cookies in the IE. But I do not know what exactly I should expect.
(I also tried to pass cookies that I received via a (Http)WebRequest/(Http)WebResponse to a WebClient but again to no avail - I am not including it here to save space).

I would very much appreciate any input.  If someone wants to run the code, I can actually provide the actual login/password information (registration on that web site is free anyway).

Comment: Yes, please provide the login/password information.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov : I included the login/password in the code; additionally, I set the UserAgent property (it still fails to lo login)

Comment: I have removed the login and password data and references to specific web pages from the code. I have solved it. In short, the authorization_param string that I used was wrong (I found it out with the help of the Firefox Tamper Data add-on), and VERY importantly I had to set the MyLoginRequest.AllowAutoRefresh property to false. I will probably post a more detailed reply later for others who may experience the same problem.